# Flutter pass a value to a global variable

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using flutter and stackoverflow for the first time, forgive me errors.
I have global variables in a global.dart file.
In my main I want to access and edit a variable by passing it the value

```
Global.dart
String nome_impianto1 = "IMPIANTO 1";
String nome_impianto2 = "IMPIANTO 2";
String nome_impianto3 = "IMPIANTO 3";
String nome_impianto4 = "IMPIANTO 4";

main.dart
import 'package:services/global.dart' as globals;
globals.nome_impianto1 = usrcontroller_ovrelay_impianto.text;  //so it works.
```

how can I pass the value I want to change?

```
globals.nome_impianto{$'1'} = usrcontroller_ovrelay_impianto.text //I know it doesn't work, and just to get the idea;
```

thank to all
Best regards
Andrea

Comment: Better user a Map like `var globals = {};` then `globals["key"] = value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Avoid using global variables in flutter. If you are managing state gloabally use `StatefulWidget` and even better start using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or even more advanced [bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc).
2. For your question, if you want to access these globally it is better to use a `Map`

```dart
//  Global.dart
  Map<String, String> globals = {
    "nome_impianto1": "IMPIANTO 1",
    "nome_impianto2": "IMPIANTO 2",
    "nome_impianto3": "IMPIANTO 3",
    "nome_impianto4": "IMPIANTO 4",
  };

// main.dart
  int index = 1;
  globals["nome_impianto$index"] = usrcontroller_ovrelay_impianto.text;
```

3. flutter doesn't have reflection https://stackoverflow.com/a/49871692/8608146

Answer (score 0):

Add this to any of your function:

```
 setState((){
      globals.nome_impianto1 = usrcontroller_ovrelay_impianto.text;
    });
```