# Flutter how i can load list from other file?

Tags: list, flutter

I want to load a list from a file into a widget, I have several lists and a specific list with an id should be loaded.

This is my code:

`main`

```
 class Cars extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _carsState createState() => _carsState();
}

class _carsState extends State<cars> {
  List clist = [
     {'id': 'l0', 'name': 'BMW'},
     {'id': 'l1', 'name': 'Audi'},
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: clist.map((info) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: RaisedButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
              ),
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text(
                info['name'],
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Cars(name: info['name'], id: info['id'],)),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

`cars.dart`

```
 class Cars extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  var id;

  Cars({Key key, this.name, this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(name),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column(
      children: LISTFROMOTHERFILE.map((info) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Text(info['name'])
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ));
  }
}
```

`list.dart`

```
      List l0 = [
  {'name': 'Example', 'PS': '500'},
  {'name': 'Example2', 'PS': '300'},
];

List l1 = [
  {'name': 'Example', 'PS': '300'},
];
```

Now, if, for example, the ID 1 is transferred from the main, I would like the list `l0` to be loaded!

How can I realize this or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I would look into JSON for this. Loads of documentation on this

Answer (score 0):

Better to make POJO class of your list

```
class ExampleList{
   final String id;
   final String name ;
   final String PS;
   /// implement [fromJson] and [toJson] method if needed
}
```

now whenever you need of it then just pass the whole object rather than passing strings.

you can use it like this

```
 Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Cars(ExampleList:ExampleList)),
                );
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I wanna do

Comment: oops! sorry. Now realize 
please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871170/flutter-how-to-get-variable-based-on-passed-string-name

Comment: no, that's different too, I have different lists and would like to load a list depending on which id is transferred from the main, the lists are in turn in an extra file in the list.dart